How to correctly merge different correlations?
My situation is like this: I have 10 users, 5 actions and 8 devices. I computed the Pearson correlation values between different devices for the same action, but I end up with many different values which I cannot really compare.
What I would like to do: right now I have a chart for each user, showing the correlations for couples of actions and for all 8 devices. So I end up with quite a lot of values, and I'd like to have a way of putting them all together for all the users. Would simply averaging the values work here? Or should I use something more sophisticated?

Correlation makes sense only for numerical variables, are any of your variables numeric?

What is it that you are correlating?

@user2974951: yes, all of them. I basically monitor values coming from sensors from users performing such activities. Then I look at the correlation between values provided by one sensor compared to another one

What specifically would the "putting them all together" represent and how do you hope it would be related to the individual Pearson coefficients?

@whuber I'd like to have a representation of how the correlation is among the different tests

But what would that mean?  You already have correlations within tests.  What would a correlation "among different tests" measure, reflect, or reveal about your data?

Nothing more, I am just looking for a more concise representation of it, otherwise I end up with too many charts.

I don't know if it's applicable here, but a common way is to Fisher's z-transform the correlations, average the transformed values, and back-transform the average.

Would "concise representation" include possible visualizations?

Yes it is exactly about visualizations

That seems to conflict with your question, which at the end refers to "averaging."  If you're really trying to ask about ways to visualize a large set of related correlation coefficients, then please edit your post accordingly.

Can you please  edit your post to include new info in comments? We want posts to be self-contained, and info only in commentswill be seen by few people!
